# Workflow manager WorflowHostUri

Tags: workflow, manager

I cant find any reference to what exactly the -WorkflowHostURI is for. Do I need to create the URI first? or does the tag create the URI for me? is that the site I need to go to manage my workflows once its created and finally what do the examples translate to for someone who have the administration skills of a 4 year old? Because otherwise I am copying and pasting it exactly as the examples are written.

Answer (score 0):

**WorkflowHostURI** is the url of the Workflow services, Once you install and configure the **Workflow Manager** then you will see IIS site for the **Workflow Manager**( typically called Workflow Management Site).

This site configured on **12290**(for https) and **12291**(for Http). URL usually server name:port number

This is end point for the WF manager service as we have for other service applications.

As per the Technet.

> WorkflowHostUri: Specifies a string of the full URI for the Workflow
>   Service.

in order to get the URI url: http://Servername:12290 or 12291( depend upon Https or http).

So on the server where u see the workflow managet Site in the IIS then that is the ServerName.

Here's the command that worked for my environment where my SharePoint URL is **http://sp.apple.com** and the Web Front End server is named **sharepointwfe**.
*Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://sp.apple.com" -WorkflowHostUri "http://sharepointwfe:12291" -AllowOAuthHttp*

Comment: Great! I dont want to sound like a moron but I am in these areas. Where can I find the full URL for the Workflow Management Site within IIS? All I can get is a localhost version of it. I need that address in order to complete this workflow registration

Comment: still not working as of set the Register script does tell me to look at the InnerException but I am unclear where that InnerException would be stored. I assume I need to find out via researching on SharePoint Management Shell

Comment: what the error you are getting? could you please share the screen print

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it now its not giving me an error but its taking forever to show any evidence that its done or have started.

My issue (I think) was that I had the site collection also in the URL for the workflow. I (think) its just the servername and port